# Swift - Cannot make PickerView Library to Work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, pickerview

I am trying to integrate this library in my project

https://github.com/filipealva/PickerView

As instructed, I added a UIView in the interface builder and created the @IBOutlet connection to the view.

Here is the code from my controller

```
import UIKit
import PickerView

class SignUpStep1ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var dayPicker: PickerView!

    var months = [
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dayPicker.delegate = self
        dayPicker.dataSource = self
        configureDayPicker()
        title = "BIRTH DATE"
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.nextBtn?.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
    }

    @IBAction func nextBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpStep2ViewController", sender: self)
    }

    fileprivate func configureDayPicker() {
        print("DayPicker Configuration")
        dayPicker.scrollingStyle = .default
        dayPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        dayPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dayPicker.scrollingStyle = PickerView.ScrollingStyle(rawValue: 1)!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension SignUpStep1ViewController: PickerViewDataSource {

    func pickerViewNumberOfRows(_ pickerView: PickerView) -> Int {
        return months.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, titleForRow row: Int, index: Int) -> String {
        return months[index]
    }
}

extension SignUpStep1ViewController: PickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerViewHeightForRows(_ pickerView: PickerView) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, didSelectRow row: Int) {

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, didTapRow row: Int, index: Int) {

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, styleForLabel label: UILabel, highlighted: Bool) {
        if highlighted {
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0)
            label.textColor = view.tintColor
        } else {
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
            label.textColor = .lightGray
        }
    }
}
```

It shows that the IBOutlet connection is created in the controller, however the picker does not show in the view, what is going wrong here?

Here is the screenshot of storyboard view.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you changed the class to `PickerView` in `Identity Inspector`?

Comment: Yes, I did change it, I noticed that datasource and delgate are being called, the problem is the view is not being displayed.

Comment: have you tried to debug delegate and datasource method? Is it execute properly?

Comment: Yes, I did debug by adding a print statement to see if it is running, and the print statement does get executed, I am not sure why the view is being hidden, let me upload the screenshot of storyboard (view)

Comment: Attached few screenshots of storyboard configuration.

Comment: Try to remove "PickerView" Class from Module in Storyboard. Just add on Class field and press tab.

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: I tried with the example project in github repository, it works in there, I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the red background color which means that the pickerview IS being shown (the red background is being set in configureDayPicker method). I think you are not getting the text because you are using `index` instead of `row` to access values from your array. Try changing

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, titleForRow row: Int, index: Int) -> String {
        return months[index]
}
```

to

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, titleForRow row: Int, index: Int) -> String {
        return months[row]
}
```

**EDIT:**
Also, try setting your text color to be a contrast to confirm if the data is in fact being loaded (the tint color might be blending the text into the background)

Comment: I am actually not getting the red background when I run, I also changed the label color to UIColor.black, it still does not show up.

Comment: The screenshots you shared show the pickerview to be red. Did you change the labelColor in both highlighted and nonhighlighted?

Comment: Try logging the flow by using `print` statements in all the methods including delegate and datasource methods. Print out the values of key items. See what's missing there

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your view hierarchy from document outline?

Comment: Yes, one sec, let me attach

Comment: Attached the screenshot, check the last one.

Comment: Just what I suspected. Your pickerView is behind all the other views and they are covering it up. Move your pickerView to the front and it should work fine

Comment: You mean to say, move it to the bottom? I did try that as well, the problem seems to be with the view since the delegate and datasource methods are executing without any errors. how do I move it to the top?

Comment: Bringing it to front means the pickerView in your document outline should be the last view in your main view. Drag the pickerview down the list so that your view hierarcy is View->[1. bg-img, 2. next btn, 3. page control, 4. pickerview]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143247/discussion-between-ibrahim-azhar-armar-and-malik).